# How do I diagnose iOS provisioning errors with an Adobe AIR project?

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, ipad, air, flash-builder

I'm testing my Adobe AIR app for iOS across 4 different devices: an iPad 1, iPad 3, iPad Mini, and iPad Air, signing with a wildcard development provisioning profile.  The app installs and runs just fine on the iPad 3 and iPad Mini, but I get "ApplicationVerificationFailed" when I try to debug on the iPad 1 and iPad Air, and "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found," when I try to install the app through XCode, for those two devices only.

The iPad 1 has historically worked OK, though we haven't had use for it in months (in fact, I only plugged it in just to try a different device when I couldn't get the iPad Air to work.)

The iPad Air we got earlier this week, and I've been struggling to get my AIR apps installed on it.

A demo app written solely in XCode installs/debugs just fine on the iPad Air.

I've registered the iPad Air in the Apple Developer center, updated my Team & App development profiles, installed those profiles on all my devices, and updated my AIR project properties with the new .mobileprovision file.

I unzipped the .ipa, looked through the embedded.mobileprovision XML, and found my device's UDID under the ProvisionedDevices key.

I'm really stuck here.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how did you get the devices' UDIDs? As of iOS 7, you **must** do it with XCode or iTunes. The iOS API that allowed for it was deprecated in 6 and removed in 7. If you use an app to get the UDID now, it will return a number that starts with FFFFFF (or something like that)

Comment: I used iTunes to find the UDIDs.

Comment: Using ad-hoc distribution? Or otherwise making sure that the provisioning profile is on the device in question?

Comment: I'm using a (wildcard) development provision.  Both that provision and my team provision are installed on all devices.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up starting over from scratch.  I deleted all my certificates & provisions, and entirely rebuilt my development Mac.

I suspect that the issue involved my having multiple Mac users linked to the same developer user account.  One obvious issue: each user had a different set of private keys for the certificates, with no user having a full set of keys.  I also occasionally had file permission issues on that Mac, with one user being abandoned entirely, because he kept creating files with messed up permissions.

Or it could've been a very simple certificate issue, and I just needed to revoke/reissue/rebuild.

In future, I'm only going to have 1 developer user on my Mac, and I'm going to let XCode manage my certificates and provisions as much as I can.